# Express app (with TypeScript ) not responding to routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have the following problem :

Im making a rest api but my app doesnt even go into the actions when I make a request to the endpoint ?

This is my server setup

```js
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import characterRouter from '../modules/character/router';
import userRouter from '../modules/user/router';
import itemsRouter from '../modules/item/router';

require('dotenv').config();

const app: Express = express();

app.use(cors);

//Setup cookieParser and public folder
app.use(cookieParser());

//Setup bodyParser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    console.log('OK');
    res.json({ ok: true });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server listnening on port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

Its my first time using the import syntax could it possibly be because of it ?

When I make a request GET localhost:3000/items it doesnt even go to the console.log

Tsconfig.json :

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true, 
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true, 
        "skipLibCheck": true,
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compiled your typescript code?

Comment: I just compiled it but still no response from the api. 
Im new to TypeScript. When I run my app do I need to run it throug index.ts or dist/index.js. Because tight now I run it through index.ts

Comment: Did you tried to run `index.ts`? Then you did it wrong. You need to run `dist/index.js`. You can make a npm script to run your app with `tsc && node ./dist/index.js`

Comment: I just fixed it but still no response from api. Can my tsconfig be the problem here ?

Comment: Do you even get the console message `Server listening ...etc`. I suggest you reduce the code the simplest required subset and test that first. I used node.js with `const express = require("express"); const app=express(); ` then put your app.get and app.listen and it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah I get the message 'Server listnening'

Comment: How are you testing the api? Do you get the response body?

Comment: Figured it out. I think either the npm cors was bugging me or the cookie-parser npm. I deleted them and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import characterRouter from '../modules/character/router';
import userRouter from '../modules/user/router';
import itemsRouter from '../modules/item/router';

require('dotenv').config();

const app: Express = express();

app.use(cors);

//Setup cookieParser and public folder
app.use(cookieParser());

//Setup bodyParser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// You missing
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    console.log('OK');
    res.json({ ok: true });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server listnening on port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```